# Angular ZoneAwareError in Angular Routing

Tags: angular, routes

I'm new to Angular and I try to implement component routing.
However, I always get an error (copied from browser control):

```
> ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'isPromise' of undefined at Object.eval (http://localhos……}
> message : (...) name : (...) originalErr : TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'isPromise' of undefined at Object.eval
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:375:68)
> at execute
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:4144:30)
> at linkDynamicModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3252:32)
> at getModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3220:9)
> at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3256:16
> at require
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3893:29)
> at Object.eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:10:15) at
> eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:42:4) at eval
> (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:43:3) at eval (<anonymous>)
> at SystemJSLoader.__exec
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1510:18)
> at entry.execute
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3926:18)
> at linkDynamicModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3252:32)
> at getModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3220:9)
> at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3256:16
> message : "Cannot read property 'isPromise' of undefined" stack :
> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPromise' of undefined↵    at
> Object.eval
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:375:68)↵
> at execute
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:4144:30)↵
> at linkDynamicModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3252:32)↵
> at getModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3220:9)↵
> at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3256:16↵
> at require
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3893:29)↵
> at Object.eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:10:15)↵    at
> eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:42:4)↵    at eval
> (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:43:3)↵    at eval
> (<anonymous>)↵    at SystemJSLoader.__exec
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1510:18)↵
> at entry.execute
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3926:18)↵
> at linkDynamicModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3252:32)↵
> at getModule
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3220:9)↵
> at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3256:16"
> __proto__ : Error originalStack : (...) stack : (...) toSource : function () toString : function () zoneAwareStack : (...)
> __zone_symbol__currentTask : ZoneTask
> __zone_symbol__error : Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPromise' of undefined at Object.eval
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:375:68)
> at Object.eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:10:15) at
> eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:42:4) at eval
> (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:43:3) at eval (<anonymous>)
> Evaluating http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js Evaluating
> http://localhost:61230/app/main.js Error loading
> http://localhost:61230/app/main.js at Object.eval
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:375:68)
> at Object.eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:10:15) at
> eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:42:4) at eval
> (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:43:3) at eval (<anonymous>)
> Evaluating http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js Evaluating
> http://localhost:61230/app/main.js Error loading
> http://localhost:61230/app/main.js at addToError
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:123:78)
> [<root>] at linkSetFailed
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:718:15)
> [<root>] at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:653:9
> [<root>] at doDynamicExecute
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:801:7)
> [<root>] at link
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1000:20)
> [<root>] at doLink
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:652:7)
> [<root>] at updateLinkSetOnLoad
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:700:18)
> [<root>] at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:512:11
> [<root>] at Zone.run
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:43)
> [<root> => <root>] at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:713:57
> [<root>] at Zone.runTask
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:166:47)
> [<root> => <root>] at drainMicroTaskQueue
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:546:35)
> [<root>] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:25)
> [<root>]
> __zone_symbol__stack : "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPromise' of undefined↵      at Object.eval
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:375:68)↵ 
> at Object.eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:10:15)↵     
> at eval (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:42:4)↵      at eval
> (http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js:43:3)↵      at eval
> (<anonymous>)↵    Evaluating
> http://localhost:61230/app/app.module.js↵ Evaluating
> http://localhost:61230/app/main.js↵   Error loading
> http://localhost:61230/app/main.js↵    at addToError
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:123:78)
> [<root>]↵    at linkSetFailed
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:718:15)
> [<root>]↵    at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:653:9
> [<root>]↵    at doDynamicExecute
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:801:7)
> [<root>]↵    at link
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1000:20)
> [<root>]↵    at doLink
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:652:7)
> [<root>]↵    at updateLinkSetOnLoad
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:700:18)
> [<root>]↵    at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:512:11
> [<root>]↵    at Zone.run
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:43)
> [<root> => <root>]↵    at
> http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:713:57
> [<root>]↵    at Zone.runTask
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:166:47)
> [<root> => <root>]↵    at drainMicroTaskQueue
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:546:35)
> [<root>]↵    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke
> (http://localhost:61230/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:25)
> [<root>]" get message : function () set message : function (value) get
> name : function () set name : function (value) get originalStack :
> function () set originalStack : function (value) get stack : function
> () set stack : function (value) get zoneAwareStack : function () set
> zoneAwareStack : function (value)
> __proto__ : Object
```

My module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component'
import { CandidateMainComponent } from './components/candidates/main.component'

    //enter code here
    //enter code here

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CandidateMainComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
         { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
         { path: 'home', component: CandidateMainComponent, data: { name: 'candidate' } },
         { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },
        ])
    ] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This happens every time and none of the routes work.
What should I do? Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you given `baseurl` to index.html?